# Windows 7 - "No application has been setup for this file type" for Daemon Tools Lite files (.iso, .mdfs, etc)

Tags: windows-7, file-association

I've been having a pain getting this fixed...

I dont really know how it happened, I suspect it was related to CCleaner, but can't be sure. I went to mount an .iso file and got an error saying something to the like of "No application has been setup for this file type" - While thats not the 100% exact way it was said, that is what it mean.

Now, I also noticed that the icon had changed, and instead of being Daemon Tools Lite icon, it was another icon, akin to the windows "I can't find your icon" icon.

Now, at first I couldn't even go "Open With", and thus I restored the backup CCleaner made, as I had just ran it for the first time since my laptop's HDD had died (about a month or two back)

This let me set the "Open with" to Daemon Tools. But, now I get from Daemon Tools "Error in Command Line". Looking around on my computer, this has affected all files normally opened with Daemon Tools.

How can I fix this? I know somewhere there is a... "thing" for setting the file extensions and their association, but I cant find it, and its really being a pain

-Edit

Now, here's something I've found - If I go into Daemon Tools, and tell it to be the file association with .isos, it will cause windows to go back to asking what program I want to open with. Something strange is going on.

Also, I have tried reinstalling Daemon Tools

Comment: Have you tried simply (uninstalling and) reinstalling Daemon Tools?

Comment: Ah yes, I have. No dice. Will put that in the question

Comment: Try uninstalling DT (you have to [manually remove](http://www.daemon-help.com/en/installation_notes_lite/manual_uninstallation_lite.html) the SPTD driver), then go to the registry and delete all its associated extensions from `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`. Now reinstall and see what happens. Edit: Ah, I see from your self-answer below that it helped.

Comment: Yes. The link I posted was where I got the answer from, but had I seen your comment first, I would have tried it

Comment: Hardly matters, as long as it's fixed. :)

Comment: Ah, CCLeaner kills another one.

Comment: @AthomSfere I don't think CCleaner directly killed this one - it just added to it, since when I restored the backup it still had the underlying issue. But still, I get your point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue relates to (At a guess) a corrupted RegEntry!

At the very least, the fix is simple.

Follow the instructions here:

http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1142998-daemon-tools-lite-problem/

Which I will quote:

- running regedit
- delete HKCR.iso DAEMON.Tools.Lite, delete it
- delete HKCR\DAEMON.Tools.Lite
- Run Daemon Tools Lite, untick integration, Apply, retick integration, Apply

Fix it, and now its running fine